# How to show Progress in percentage while Api call without using Asynctask in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, progressdialog

**Purpose** : I am using `progress dialog` while making an `api` call using `retrofit` library. for that i am using below code :

```
private var progressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun showProgress(message: String?, context: Context?, cancellable: Boolean) {
            if (context == null)
                return

            if (checkProgressOpen())
                return
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
            (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)
            (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).setMessage(message ?: "Please wait...")
            (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).setCancelable(cancellable)
            try {
                (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).show()


            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // catch exception for activity paused and dialog is going to be
                // show.
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun checkProgressOpen(): Boolean {
            if (progressDialog != null && (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).isShowing())
                return true
            else
                return false
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun cancelProgress() {
            if (checkProgressOpen()) {
                try {
                    (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).dismiss()
                    (progressDialog as ProgressDialog).cancel()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                progressDialog = null
            }
        }
```

this code is working fine. It is showing `progress dialog` , But what i want now is show that `progress dialog` in percentage.

like when `api call` starts `dialog` should start from percentage 0 and it should update percentage at some interval , and when `Api call` completes `dialog` should display percentage 100.

I have done R&D on this , but everywhere what i m getting is , using `asynctask`
and it's method `OnProgressUpdate` , but i don't wan to use `asynctask`.

Can anyone helps me in this ?? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: it would be quite hard with retrofit. You will have to intersect the requests, and even go deeper after that. But usually te requests are done too fast to display their progress in %. Only place where the % is suitable is uploading\downloading files.

Comment: can i use that code of showing % while downloading into making an api call ??

Comment: `while downloading` what?

Comment: u r saying that % is suitable while downloading files, then can i use that code while making an api call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom `RequestBody` and use it as `RequestBody` in `Retrofit`. Here is sample of `ProgressRequestBody`

This will provide you update of porgress. You can customize this as per your need.

```
open class ProgressRequestBody(private val mFile: File) : RequestBody() {

    private val ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls: Int = 0

    private var numWriteToCalls = 0

    private val getProgressSubject: PublishSubject<Pair<Float, File>> = PublishSubject.create<Pair<Float, File>>()

    fun getProgressSubject(): Observable<Pair<Float, File>> {
        return getProgressSubject
    }

    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        return MediaType.parse("application/pdf")
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun contentLength(): Long {
        return mFile.length()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
        numWriteToCalls++

        val fileLength = mFile.length()
        val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        val `in` = FileInputStream(mFile)
        var uploaded: Long = 0
        var lastProgressPercentUpdate = 0f
        `in`.use { `in` ->
            var read: Int
            read = `in`.read(buffer)
            while (read != -1) {

                uploaded += read.toLong()
                sink.write(buffer, 0, read)
                read = `in`.read(buffer)
                //GLOBAL_PROGRESS.onNext(uploaded)
                // when using HttpLoggingInterceptor it calls writeTo and passes data into a local buffer just for logging purposes.
                // the second ic_call to write to is the progress we actually want to track
                if (numWriteToCalls > ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls) {
                    val progress = (uploaded.toFloat() / fileLength.toFloat()) * 100f
                    //prevent publishing too many updates, which slows upload, by checking if the upload has progressed by at least 1 percent
                    if (progress - lastProgressPercentUpdate > 1 || progress == 100f) {
                        // publish progress
                        getProgressSubject.onNext(Pair(progress, mFile))
                        lastProgressPercentUpdate = progress

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048
    }

}
```